# HTTP 500 Error after migrating WordPress to new host

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to move my WordPress site to new host and getting 500 error on new host.
www.thetechpie.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I think the cause of this problem is directory difference.
Like my previous directory was /home/user1/web/domain.tld/public_html
and new one is /home/user2/web/domain.tld/public_html

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should provide the content of `error_log`, this will be way easier to track the issue.

Comment: After migrating WordPress to new host, dont forget to change wp-config database connection data.

Answer (score 1):

It happen normally due to hosting change of directory change as you mention you have change directory there must be something bad happens during your copy/move.

To make sure ever thing works perfect you should try these methods...

1. You should go is your hosting file manager and replace .htaccess file from another new one. (If not working for you then go for second one)
2. Go to wp-content folder there you will find plugin folder just rename it with any thing (for example i have assume _plugin ) now go to you site/wp-admin, you will find your login page , enter your id password and login into your dashboard go to setting -> permalinks -> then change the permalinks options and save it . Now go back again to your file manger and rename your _plugin folder as plugin . come back to your dashboard reload it , go to plugins and activate all plugin back which you find useful for your site.

Here is the links for my research :-

- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/500-internal-server-error/
- http://www.1tech.in/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you updated the DNS nameservers to the new host. It seems the browser cannot find the domain name on your new server.

Besides, make sure that you have added the new correct directory path to the domain name on your new server.

Also, after updating the DNS nameservers, go to the "Permalinks" setting and click on "Save" button. It will make sure that you have all necessary .htaccess configuration on the new host.

### Who.is:

From https://who.is/whois/thetechpie.com I can see, your current DNS nameserver are:

`karl.ns.cloudflare.com 173.245.59.190
kate.ns.cloudflare.com 173.245.58.124`

Are these the updated one. If not check it out again after updating your DNS nameservers.

** If you have just added updated your DNS, you may need to wait for a while to get it rendered (it generally takes some time depending on the hosting service providers).

Comment: You are seeing the CloudFlare NS because I reverted back the Nameserver to Previous One. I cannot afford much downtime :(

Comment: Also, here is what I did.
1) Copy all the files from public_html of previous host to new one.
2) Backup and replace /home/admin/ with /home/user2/ and import db into  new database
3) I get  500 error

Comment: If you have done everything I have answered above already, please make sure that there's an .htaccess available in public_html folder. If not go to "Permalinks" and just click on "Save" button. It will create a new. htaccess file for you or update the exiting one with proper setting.